# How to pass values from action result to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to pass model properties from the action to the view,
Some of my model properties going to be filled by user and some by my code.

This is my model

```
public class DocOnDemandModel
{
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string PdfUrl { get; set; }
    public string PageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

This is the action code

```
public class DocOnDemandController : Controller
{
    // GET: Request
    public ActionResult Index(string PdfUrl)
    {
        string Domain = Request.UrlReferrer.Host;
        string PageUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString;
        DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;

        ViewBag.PageUrl = PageUrl;
        ViewBag.Domain = Domain;
        ViewBag.PdfUrl = PdfUrl;
        ViewBag.Time = Time;

        return View();
    }
}
```

Name, Email and Phone number will be filled by user,
Domain, Time, pdfUrl, PageUrl will be filled by my action code

Now I need to pass Domain, Time, pdfUrl and PageUrl to the View and I tried with ViewBag but an error appearred

[image: my view:]

Can someone help me figure the problem and help me fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can directly pass model to view from action method.

Comment: Would it help if you cast them to string in your contoller? e.g. : ViewBag.Domain = Domain.ToString();

Comment: 1.Can't it be done with ViewBag?  
2. Is it possible to pass objects when the view is already getting a model?
{@model FileRequest.Models.DocOnDemandModel}

Comment: @DieterB The function ToString() isn't helping

Comment: What is the exact and full error?

Answer (score 4):

You can directly pass model to view from action method.

```
public ActionResult Index(string PdfUrl)
{
    var model = new DocOnDemandModel();
    string Domain = Request.UrlReferrer.Host;
    string PageUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString;
    DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;

    model.PageUrl = PageUrl;
    model.Domain = Domain;
    model.PdfUrl = PdfUrl;
    model.Time = Time;

    return View(model);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Domain);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.Label((string)ViewBag.Domain)
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to handle it this way
[image]

Not sure if it's the right way but it's doing the job, My code remains the same.

Comment: Definitely it's not the right way. I suggest you to go as per my answer.